# Touch event: when touches the image call function and remove image

Tags: lua

I am using touch event function in my game. While touching the image it is calling the function and in the same time it has to remove that image. Kindly help me friends.

Code:

```
local img=display.newImageRect("bingo.png",451,369)         
function img:touch( event )
if event.phase == "began" then

    newgame()
end
    return true
end 
img:addEventListener( "touch", img )
```